# How to create a sharable Django repository on Github

Tags: django, github, repository

Having trouble creating a Django repository on Github that everyone can use? I tried pushing the entire virtual environment at first, found out that it doesn't work like that, then I tried just pushing the Django folder, but even the manage.py is looking for a path that only exists on my PC.

How can I push the Django project, so that my group members can pull it, work on it, test it, and be able to push their changes themselves? Do we all have to be using the same virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was missing:

```
python manage.py migrate w
```

I tested this a couple times pushing it and pulling it from my PC and laptop.

I'm going to push the Django project onto our repository in a bit so we can start working on stuff. I'm still learning all this so this might not be entirely correct—do correct me if I'm wrong—but this worked for me. (I pushed a Django project onto my git from my laptop, cloned it onto my PC, and ran it.)

- Create a folder; call it whatever you want
- Install your virtual environment into this folder

  - I'm using `venv`, but all VEs should work (for `venv`, `python -m venv .`; the dot installs it in the current directory)
- When you clone the repository, clone it in this same folder; or, if the repository doesn't exist yet, create it here; don't go into the folder yet
- After it's cloned, activate your virtual environment
- Once your VE is active, go into our repo folder (`DroneWebsite`)
- Go into the `src` folder
- ```
  pip install django==3.2.7
  ```
- ```
  python manage.py migrate
  ```
- It should be good to go! To test:

  ```
  python manage.py runserver
  ```